# How to store ouput of FOR XML Path in a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to store the output of for XML Path in a variable. However this doesn't work:

```
Declare @Tab    dbo.SingleColumnTable

Insert INTO @Tab

Values(
    'Jack'
)

Insert INTO @Tab

Values(
    'Armageddon'
)

Declare @RetVal varchar(8000) = ''

Select Top 1 @RetVal = Data
From
(
    Select ';' + ' ' + Name as 'Data'
               From @Tab t2
               for xml path('')
) v
```

As you can see I am trying to set the column name of returned output as Data but it doesn't work. I get error `Invalid column name 'Data'.`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try changing

```
Select Top 1 @RetVal = Data 
From 
( 
    Select ';' + ' ' + Name as 'Data' 
               From @Tab t2 
               for xml path('') 
) v
```

to

```
Select @RetVal = 
( 
    Select ';' + ' ' + Name as Data
   From @Tab t2 
   for xml path('') 
)
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4784/0)